# Place control over other

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, controls

I am searching a way to put a ComboBox over another Control with xaml. The new combobox should aligned on the right side of the window.
How can I do this?
Best Regards, Thomas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Grid panel. If you do not specify Row/Column of the controls inside the Grid, they will overlap.

Another solution is to use Canvas layout, which is almost like what you have on WinForms, where you can set X/Y of the control and you have more control on where they should appear.

Comment: +1. Yes, but to be more precise if you specify the same column and row in the Grid for two controls they will overlap.